# mongodb how to get a document which has max value of each "group with the same key"

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a collection:

```
{'_id':'008','name':'ada','update':'1504501629','star':3.6,'desc':'ok', ...}
{'_id':'007','name':'bob','update':'1504501614','star':4.2,'desc':'gb', ...}
{'_id':'005','name':'ada','update':'1504501532','star':3.2,'desc':'ok', ...}
{'_id':'003','name':'bob','update':'1504501431','star':4.5,'desc':'bg', ...}
{'_id':'002','name':'ada','update':'1504501378','star':3.4,'desc':'no', ...}
{'_id':'001','name':'ada','update':'1504501325','star':3.6,'desc':'ok', ...}
{'_id':'000','name':'bob','update':'1504501268','star':4.3,'desc':'gg', ...}
...
```

if I want the result is, the max value of 'update' of the same 'name', means the newest document of 'name', get the whole document:

```
{'_id':'008','name':'ada','update':'1504501629','star':3.6,'desc':'ok', ...}
{'_id':'007','name':'bob','update':'1504501614','star':4.2,'desc':'gb', ...}
...
```

**How to do it most effective?**

I do it now in python is:

```
result=[]
for name in db.collection.distinct('name'):
    result.append(db.collection.find({'name':name}).sort('update',-1)[0])
```

is it do 'find' too many times?

=====

I do this for crawl data with 'name', get many other keys, and every time I insert a document, I set a key named 'update'.
When I using the database, I want the newest **document** of specific 'name'. so it looks can not just use $group.
How should I do? re design the db structure or better way to find?

=====

Improved !
I've tried create index of 'name' & 'update', the process is shortened from half hour to 30 seconds!

But I still welcome for better solution ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case scenario suits real good for aggregation. As I see in your question you already know that but can't figure out how to use `$group` and take whole document that has the max update. If you `$sort` your documents before `$group`you can use `$first`operator. So no need to send a find query for each name.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{ $sort: { "name": 1, "update": -1 } },
{ $group: { _id: "$name", "update": { $first: "$update" }, "doc_id": { $first: "$_id" } } }
)
```

I did not add an extra `$project`operation to aggregate, you can just add fields that you want in result to `$group`with `$first`operator.

Additionally, if you look closer to `$sort`operation, you can see it uses your newly created index, so you did good to add that, otherwise I will recommend it too :)

**Update:** For your question in comment:

You should write all keys in `$group`. But if you think it will look bad or new fileds will come in future and does not want to rewrite `$group`each time, I would do that:

First get all `_id`fields of desired documents in aggregation and then get these documents in one `find`query with `$in`operator.

`db.collection.find( { "_id": { $in: [<ids returned in aggregation] } } )`

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried aggregation, but if use $group, as your method, I can get 3 keys only. But I want the whole document, not only the '_id'.  
Yesterday I've tried an other way, use aggregation $sort all data in collection, load in python, and remove duplicates. The process was shortened to 6 seconds.  
But now, the collection have 120k+ documents, and 26k unique 'name' would be take every time. If the collection become bigger, take whole collection data should be slower.

Comment: or shold I write all the keys in $group? I've 40+ keys...

Comment: Fine, I've tried list all keys in $group, It used 25 seconds, same to my old method.

Comment: Yes, for current data set it does not effect much, but you said earlier when your dataset gets bigger, taking whole collection would be painful and make unnecessary network traffic. In this way, working with bigger dataset will not effect you, you will always ask mongoDB to give documents you interest.

Comment: I found a problem that I run it on a network machine which is the 'SECONDARY', when I run it on the 'PRIMARY', 3.6 seconds!!! So Great!!! and very thank you ^_^